# How to find equilibrium rpm of a wind-turbine / free-spinning rotor (using BEM)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, aerodynamics

Background: I want to design a rotor-recovery system, which uses a free-spinning rotor to slow a fall instead of a parachute for example. From a mechanics and aerodynamic standpoint it should work basically identical to a wind turbine, meaning an inflow (induced by the falling velocity) generates a spinning motion and therefore lift.

I looked into blade element momentum theory as it should give satisfactory results and I'd like to skip CFD. I watched the BYU Flow lab series on Youtube on that topic and have a good but basic understanding of undergrad fluid mechanics.

Problem: most BEM theory explanations talk of 'operating conditions' as input which include the rotational velocity, as do all Codes that solve the problem numerically need some input rpm. Those are generally geared towards helicopter design, where you can set a certain rpm due to an engine. I don't know the rpm, neither would you know it in a wind turbine. My first instinct would be to say: 'Okay, there is a equilibrium rpm for a given inflow velocity, in that case the parts of lift and drag of a given blade which act in normal direction to the inflow should be in equilibrium, the rotor should therefore neither rotational accelerate nor decelerate.' This would in consequence mean that there is no torque going out of the propeller/wind turbine, which would mean that a turbine would not generate power. Furthermore, if I were to solve the equilibrium force condition to find an equilibrium rpm, I would need the tangential induction factor a' which itself would go to zero (as a result of the equilibrium condition).

Now, my question: how would you find the equilibrium rpm of a free spinning rotor, given all geometries, lift/drag coefficients and inflow velocity but no experimental values (as TSR or similar)? I feel like I'm missing something bigger here, but I also feel like that one should be able to 'swap' the input condition of rpm for (numerically equivalent) condition of 'non-powered' rotor.

Comment: Some times ago [I gave an overview](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/95476/64684) about BEM on aviation.se, let me know if it matches with what you've learnt on YouTube.

Comment: @sophit Yes this matches what I learned on youtube, I also know about axial and tangential induction factors, correction factors for tip losses, etc., the lecture got I think through the whole theory. Unfortunately your link also assumes a forced rotation and not a free, flow-induced one. Would it make sense to double-post this question to aviation.se?

Comment: I just wanted to know if we were synchronised on the terminology :) Ok, then you should be able to adapt the theory to the autorotation case ;)